# restore the hidden state of a LSTM network in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, lstm

I am using a LSTM in my model and my forward function is defined as:

```
self.rnn = nn.LSTM(...)

def forward(self, input, hidden):
   #  dropout, linear embedding
    emb = self.drop(self.encoder(input.contiguous().view(-1, self.num_in_features)))  
    emb = emb.view(-1, input.size(1), self.rnn_hid_size)

    output, hidden = nn.LSTM(emb, hidden)
    output = self.drop(output)
    # [(seq_len x batch_size) * feature_size]
    decoded = self.decoder(output.view(output.size(0) * output.size(1), output.size(2)))
    # [ seq_len, batch_size, feature_size]
    decoded = decoded.view(output.size(0), output.size(1), decoded.size(1))

    return decoded, hidden, output
```

I am doing some inference as follows:

```
model.eval()
hidden = model.init_hidden(1)


with torch.no_grad():
    for i in range(end_point):
        if i >= start_point:
            out, hidden, _ = model.forward(out, hidden)
       else:
            out, hidden, _ = model.forward(my_input_seq[i].unsqueeze(0), hidden)
```

Now after I run this statement

```
out, hidden, _ = model.forward(out, hidden)
```

After I get the output, I want to undo this statement i.e. restore the LSTM state to before the call. I am guessing this would mean somehow undoing or restoring the hidden state to before the call. What would be a fast (and hopefully easy) way to achieve this in pytorch?

Comment: Please provide information when you ask links elsewhere, as I have just found your exact same question in the PyTorch forums, see [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/copy-and-restore-the-hidden-state-of-a-rnn-network/71199)....